# Will resetting my router cause all my VPN connections to no longer work?

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I have a Cisco RV320 router. I need to reset it due to forgetting our login credentials for the router settings page at 192.168.1.1. However, the computer connected to the router has VPN connections to multiple destinations with its static IP address.

Will resetting the Cisco router cause those VPN connections to no longer work? If they don't work, will we need to reregister all the VPN connections then?

Answer (score 0):

Resetting a router will not directly impact anything outside router.

As long as the computer holding VPN connections can once again connect to the Internet, all VPN connections to VPN servers on the Internet work.

The only thing that needs proper configuration is related to VPN servers on your local network. But if I had to rely on my hunches, I'd say you don't have such a thing.

Comment: This router is a **VPN Router**, so it is fairly easy to assume that the VPN he's talking about are hosted/configured on this router.

Comment: @YisroelTech Don't assume then. He said "the computer connected to the router has VPN connections".

Comment: One should definitely try to assume things! I never had clients that told me/knew the whole story. And I wish you don't want him to reset and then come back crying that he lost everything